# No such module 'AWSCognitoAuthPlugin' even when the pod is installed

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, aws-amplify

my Podfile is

```
pod 'Amplify'
pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSAPIPlugin'
pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'
pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSS3StoragePlugin'
pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSDataStorePlugin'
```

[I have added the dependancy in the build phases before importing here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT6Ce.png)

I have clean build the project.
I have deleted the pod and reinstalled. I am opening .workspace file only.I am able to

`import Amplify`
and  `import AWSPluginsCore`
without any issue. but I get `No such module 'AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'`
when I try to `import AWSCognitoAuthPlugin`
If I am missing something, please point it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `pod 'AmplifyPlugins/AWSCognitoAuthPlugin'` 2 times in your Podfile but that is not what's making this issue.

It seems that Amplify podspec have some issues. My recommendation is to use SPM when using Amplify because this problem doesn't persist there.

Also, there is no new versions of Amplify on Cocoapods.org (last 1.30.4) and on SPM there are (last 2.15.1)